# Enable local flash in IWebBrowser2 control

Tags: iwebbrowser2

I'm trying to load local html pages that contain local flash components using IWebBrowser2 control.

I've put a `.cfg` file in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerTrust` with a path to the relevant directory.

These pages run just fine in IE (after clicking the Allow Blocked Content bar). But I couldn't make then to work in IWebBrowser2 control.

[Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28VS.85%29.aspx) did not work, nor enabling ActiveX controls by implementing *[IInternetSecurityManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537130%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)*.

I've also tried `CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled` with not luck and to set: Internet Settings->Advanced->Security->Allow active content to run in the files on MyComputer.

The only solution I can think of is to use a local server as a work around, but this is realy just as a last resort.

Did someone manage to make it work? Am I missing something?

Thanks!